# Skip button from css crosshair property

Tags: html, css

I am having this html code

```
   <div>
         This is content
         <button>Continue</button>
   </div>
   <div style="cursor: crosshair; position: absolute; top: 0px; width: 200px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

It is working as expected. But the problem is it should not override the button. That is the +(plus) symbol should not be shown on button. I should able to click the button for this scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will keep your original code intact:  (Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7muPm/)

```
<html>
  <body>

   <div class='div1'>
         This is content
         <button class='butt1'>Continue</button>
   </div>

   <div class="div2"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
  cursor: crosshair;    // remove this if this div should not have crosshair
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10  
}
.div2 {
  cursor: crosshair;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 9;  
}
.butt1 {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div style="cursor: crosshair; top: 0px; width: 200px; height: 100px; float:left"></div>
```

Demo is here http://jsfiddle.net/6ZSn7/

Comment: No.. I am getting the same result

Comment: have you checked the demo i have placed?

Comment: working but the crosshair only works below the content.

Comment: yes, crosshair to empty div.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `position: absolute;top: 0px;` from your style. Remove the div below and place the style in the first div.

**HTML**

```
<div style="cursor: crosshair; width: 200px; height: 100px;">This is content
    <button>Continue</button>
</div>
```

#### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZSn7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the same layout as provided, this is an alternative solution to make the button clickable..

On button applied this CSS

```
button{z-index:1; position:relative;}
```

Here is the Demo http://jsbin.com/kuzujoge/1/edit